# How to use Microsoft Graph Toolkit with application permissions (client credentials)

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I would like to use Microsoft Graph Toolkit with application permissions instead of delegated permissions. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toolkit depends on an IProvider to handle the authentication and permissions - you can add a provider that authenticates using application permissions if you'd like - see [docs here on creating custom providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/custom).

If you are instead handling the authentication on the server side, then you can leverage something like the [proxy provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/proxy) which relays all requests to the graph via your own backend.

Comment: Thanks Nikola . I just saw the Graph Community Call where you were talking about the Proxy Provider so I will do that then. It would have been easier to have a ApplicationProvider included in the sdk however, any plan on implementing that in the future ?

Comment: Do you mean the .NET SDK? It's something we've been lightly considering but we that's about it. I would love it if you could create an issue on our GitHub to have a bigger discussion on what that would look like.

Comment: I meant in the microsoft-graph-toolkit. I like the idea to centralize token retrieval server side but I think it should be possible to use client credentials in the front as well with a future "ApplicationProvider".  Furthermore Proxy Provider is nice but from what I saw on your repository sample it requires a bit of .net code to make it work properly. Which Github repository do you mean for a discussion about it?

Comment: Yeah, please open an issue at our repo and let's have a discussion on what exactly this could look like: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit

Answer (score -3):

The Microsoft Graph Toolkit is a great resource for any developer looking to create a web app, Microsoft Teams tab, or SharePoint web part that makes calls to Microsoft Graph. By providing UI components that are designed to look and feel like Microsoft 365 experiences, the Toolkit reduces your time and cost to integrate with the platform. All the UI components authenticate with and access data from Microsoft Graph. The components are fully customizable using CSS and templating so you can match your unique branding and control the content displayed in the components.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/overview